# angular-jsdoc with npm

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, documentation

Using angular-jsdoc I am using this command to generate my docs

> **node .\node_modules\jsdoc\jsdoc.js app -c .\node_modules\angular-jsdoc\common\conf.json -d docs -t .\node_modules\angular-jsdoc\angular-template\**

I don't prefer typing such long command every-time I update my doc.

I would like to know some shortcut so that I can avoid typing or copy/pasting this command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the command indicates  **node** is being used for execution. I would suggest using **npm** 's functionality to create project based commands.

This can be done as follows:

1. Create a package.json file in your master directory (using npm init).
2. Add the below json object in package.json file

> "scripts": {
>       "gendoc":"node .\node_modules\jsdoc\jsdoc.js app -c .\node_modules\angular-jsdoc\common\conf.json -d docs -t .\node_modules\angular-jsdoc\angular-template\"
>     }

This will create a **gendoc** command for your project which can be executed from the command line as follows:

> npm run gendoc

Now you don't need to type entire command, just enter the above command, npm will search for the **scripts** object in **package.json** and execute the script whose key is **gendoc**.